# Use remote control for non-audio related tasks?

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

Would it be possible to use the audio controls in the multitasking tray for non-audio related tasks?

(For example, putting the app icon there, or using the buttons to respond to something else?)

Does this violate an HIG rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` and `-remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:` if you were the last app playing audio, but doing anything non-standard will be a HIG violation. There was an app which used the volume control to take pictures, but as soon as this was highlighted, the app was pulled until the developer changed the behaviour.

The WWDC 2010 Multitasking video (Part 2) has some details about using the remote.

Comment: should I use beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents and -remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: , where? in my app delegate? in my controller? thks