# Use earpods in swift

Tags: ios, swift, remote-control

I'm trying to get when you press the play / pause button of my earpods make an action. For this I am first trying to achieve change a text label ...

According to look at various websites, they performed this same but it does not work. Is there anything missing me add?

I have the following code in viewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    canBecomeFirstResponder()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var Cosa: UILabel!

func play()  {
    Cosa.text = "Play"
}

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let event = event else {
        print("no event\n")
        return
    }
    guard event.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl else {
        print("received other event type\n")
        return
    }
    switch event.subtype {
    case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay:
        print("received remote play\n")
        play()
    case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause:
        print("received remote pause\n")
    case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
        print("received toggle\n")
    default:
        print("received \(event.subtype) which we did not process\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but a code comment: Your IBOutlet "Cosa" should begin with a lowercase letter. In Obj-c and Swift names beginning with uppercase letters are expected to be Types. Member values, properties and methods should all begin with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

For any RemoteControlEvents you need to have the audio playing.

> **Preparing Your App for Remote Control Events**
>
> To receive remote control events, do the following:
>
> 1. **Register handlers for each action you support**. Use the shared
>      MPRemoteCommandCenter object to register handlers for different types
>      of events
> 2. **Begin
>      playing audio**. Your app must be the “Now Playing” app. An app does not
>      receive remote control events until it begins playing audio.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html

Also you can refer the below link for more clarification and Demo project
[Receive remote control events without audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885047/receive-remote-control-events-without-audio)